# Probability of Four Tosses of Manipulated Coin

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question regarding to a exercise:

A random experiment consists of 4 independent coin tosses. Each coin toss has a
probability of 0.6 of getting “heads” because the coin is manipulated. For the number of “heads” construct a table including the …

I know how I can make a table of this (See link below), but how can I calculate the normal probability, and how can I calculate this with a probability of "heads" 0.6?

Here you can See my table:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/343yd.jpg

Comment: This is a standard [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with success probability $p=.6$ and $4$ trials.

Answer (score 1):

The specific PDF for the distribution $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4, p=.6)$ is as follows:

$$P(X = k) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = {4\choose k}0.6^k0.4^{5-k},$$
for $k = 0,1,2,3,4.$

In R statistical software where `dbinom` is a binomial PDF, we can make a
probability table of this distribution as shown below. (Brackets
`[ ]` show line numbers, not values of `x`.)

```
x = 0:4;  pdf = dbinom(x, 4, .6)
cbind(x, pdf)
     x    pdf
[1,] 0 0.0256
[2,] 1 0.1536
[3,] 2 0.3456
[4,] 3 0.3456
[5,] 4 0.1296
```

We can use the probabilities computed above to make a plot of this
binomial distribution:

```
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, col="blue", ylim=c(0,.35), 
     main="PDF of BINOM(4, .8)")
  abline(h=0, col="green2"); abline(v=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

*Notes:* I'm not sure what you mean by 'the normal' probability.

(1) If you mean the probability
distribution for a *fair* coin then $Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=4, p =.5),$ the
PDF is $P(Y=k) = {4 \choose k}(1/2)^n,$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,4.$ Below, I have added
the appropriate fractions to the table made by R (at `3`'s.)

```
y = 0:4;  pdf = dbinom(y, 4, .5)
cbind(y, pdf)
     y    pdf
[1,] 0 0.0625  #  1/64
[2,] 1 0.2500  #  4/64
[3,] 2 0.3750  #  6/64
[4,] 3 0.2500  #  4/64
[5,] 4 0.0625  #  1/64
```

For example, $P(Y=2)$ is evaluated as follows: ${4\choose 2} = \frac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!} = \frac{24}{4} = 6$ outcomes
each with probability $\frac{1}{2^4} = \frac{1}{64}.$

(2) Maybe you mean normal approximation to the binomial probabilities.
Although some binomial probabilities can be approximated by a normal distribution,
normal approximation does not work well when $n$ is as small as $4.$